# Adding list of classes to PHP array

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I would like to use php to loop through a products categories and store them into an array, which will be assigned as class names for each product. For some reason my code is not working, and there are no PHP errors. Perhaps it is a wordpress issue:

```
$classes = array();

$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $classes[] = $term->slug;
}

<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
```

Essentially, I am trying to assign categories as class names to their respective product. This isn't throwing an error, but nothing loads. Anyone see any issues here?

Comment: did you tried printing out the array $terms?

Comment: Be careful if you're using the `post_class()` function outside the loop, you have to give a **post ID** as the second parameter : [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Display_Posts_Outside_of_the_Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Display_Posts_Outside_of_the_Loop).

Comment: I did print out $terms and get an array like this:  Array ( [19] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 19 [name] => Pendant [slug] => pendant [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 19 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [object_id] => 44 ) )

Comment: @Strategio I do not see the issue with my code... This doesnt change a thing:  <?php post_class( $classes, $post->id ); ?>. Please explain?

Comment: You have an extra "}" after foreach loop and you didn't closed "?>" php before writing html. You should enable php display_errors.

Comment: @JCHASE11 This was just a warning because I didn't know the rest of your code...

Answer (score 0):

Using array_shift to break up the array worked for me, but it does not work if $cats has mutliple classes

```
<?php $classes = array();
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat'); 

foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $cats[] = $term->slug;
}

$classes[] = implode(" ", $cats);

<li <?php post_class( $classes); ?>>
```

Comment: you should add $cats array before loop.

Comment: You mean just define $cats = array(); at the top?

Comment: using implode works? now i seriously think the problem was something else. Probably a space was needed between class names in html.